# git log after subtree merging

Tags: git, git-merge

I have successfully merged a git sub-repository into a main one's subfolder by doing a so-called [subtree merge](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/).

Say, something like that:

```
/project_B-git
 +--src/

/main-repo-git
 +--subproject_A/
 +--subproject_B/    <--- SUBTREE MERGE
    +--src/
```

Now my problem is that I cannot restrict the log history in the main repo to only the sub-history of the imported repo:

The history in the original project:

```
project_B-git$ git log --oneline 
* 76543210 Say hello, wave goodbye.
* 01234567 A message to you Rudy.
```

The complete history in the main repo after merging:

```
main-repo-git$ git log --oneline --graph
*   646bf9bb Merge subproject_B.
|\  
| * 76543210 Say hello, wave goodbye.
| * 01234567 A message to you Rudy.
|
* f71fdb10 Init.
```

The filtered history I get now:

```
main-repo-git$ git log --oneline --graph -- subproject_B/
* 646bf9bb Merge subproject_B.
* f71fdb10 Init.
```

So you see when I filter my history by path I only see the merge commit, "losing" all *subproject_B*'s history. I would like to get:

```
* 646bf9bb Merge subproject_B.
* 76543210 Say hello, wave goodbye.
* 01234567 A message to you Rudy.
```

I tried to read through the `git-log`'s manual page, but I couldn't see a way to choose a given merge branch, so that I could ask git to follow the *other* branch (`--left-only`/`--right-only` options are not doing the job).